# The Right Database (Read-Only, Tabular, Desktop, Web, C#)

Tags: c#, database

I appreciate any suggestions on a database for the following problem:

1. Contains < 200 MB read-only data
2. Data is quite tabular with limited relationship to other tables
3. Must query tabular data and put into C# structure (to be feed to an interpolation routine)
4. It will be accessed by C# routine.  This routine will exist in desktop application and behind ASP.net application.
5. Encryption required for desktop install
6. SQL not necessary
7. Component must support concurrency

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not what this site is for.

Comment: I would use SQL Server Express which is free and can be downloaded from msdn.com.  Why reinvent the wheel?  Using a serialization will create an XML file which would take longer to get queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would put the data into C# structure, and serialize it to disk. 200 MB seems like an amount, which would safely fit into RAM. While serializing/deserializing, you can pass it through [CryptoStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream(v=vs.110).aspx), and get encryption requirement covered that way. Whole database layer could be so simple, it would fit on one screen.